# HTC Incredible not downloading email from Exchange 2003 account

Tags: exchange-2003, android

I have a Exchange 2003 setup, with no SSL. I have one user who also receives his work email on his HTC Incredible. I've setup his email account as an Exchange account and to synchronize his email, contacts and calendar. About 2 weeks ago he stop receiving any new email on his HTC Incredible, so I just deleted that account and set it up again. Now about a week ago he stopped receiving his emails again.

Both times if I go to the email account settings, and make sure his settings are correct (re enter username/password) and do a verify account, it verifies correctly. However when I go to the INBOX it does not download new email.

On the INBOX view if I hit Menu -> Refresh, I see the refresh icon in the notification area appear and disappear. There are no errors reported, however no new email is download.

Anyone have any ideas how to best "debug" this?  Which diagnostic logging setting in system manager would log the android connection, if any.

Comment: You might have better luck on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the user's e-mail account also accessed by Outlook 2003? Might be corrupted events on his calendar hanging up the process.

Comment: @samarudge, hmm thanks I'll look around there. Only reason I threw it on here was because about an year ago we had a similar issue with all non blackberry phones, where the account would be verified but no actual synchronization would happen. Only way we resolved it back then was a blind trust in the good ol' "restart the server!!!" method. But I would really like to actually track the cause down, even if the solution is to restart like before.

Comment: @Chris S, The user accesses his email account from his work laptop (Outlook 2007) and his phone (HTC Incredible). How would I know if its a corrupted event on his calendar? Can I track it in Exchange 2003 diagnostic logging somehow?

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_5885707_fix-calendar-entries-microsoft-outlook.html or using the scanpst/scanost programs should fix any anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

Here some update on this issue. So I decided to run a wireshark trace for the user email sync. Setup a basic wireshark with a capture filter for port 80 and other activesync ports listed here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915152

So each time I go the faulty user's email app on the HTC Incredible, a sequence of 6 exchanges happen

```
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?Cmd=FolderSync&User=FakeUsername&DeviceId=HTCDevice&DeviceType=inc
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?Cmd=GetItemEstimate&User=FakeUsername&DeviceId=HTCDevice&DeviceType=inc
POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?Cmd=Sync&User=FakeUsername&DeviceId=HTCDevice&DeviceType=inc
```

For each one I get an error in the HTTP payload, which is activesync specific XML. To be precise it is WBXML 1.3.

The response to the FolderSync command is

```
<FolderSync>
    <Error>
    '1'
    </Error>
    <SyncKey>{A Guid}</SyncKey>
    <Changes>
        <Count>0</Count>
    </Changes>
</FolderSync>
```

The response to the GetItemEstimate is (well I'll show what I think is the relevant bit)

```
<GetItemEstimate>
    <Error>
    '1'
    </Error>
    ...
    ...
</GetItemEstimate>
```

The response to the Sync command also contains the  '1'  bit.

```
<Synchronize>
    <Folders>
        <Folder>
            <FolderType>
            'Email'
            </FolderType>
            ... folder details ...
            <Error>
           '1'
            </Error>
        </Folder>
        ...
        <Perform>
            <Remove>..</Remove>
            <Remove>..</Remove>
            <Add>..</Add>
        </Perform>
    ...
    ...
</Synchronize>
```

So although it also contains all the correct commands to update the list with the new emails (   commands) it seems like that the '1' in response to all these commands is hanging up the display of updated emails on the phone.

Anyone know if there is a list of these ActiveSync XML error codes and what they mean? Hoping I can backtrack from there and find a possible cause for this.